# Posting to a different website from from action in larval blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a form like below in a blade template file.
{{Form::open(array('url' => 'http://b.xyz.app:8000/register'))}}
This is output as below in html when we see in browser source.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://xyz.app:8000/http://b.xyz.app::8000/register" accept-charset="UTF-8"></form>
```

How do I create form element such that the prefix of the current domain "http://xyz.app:8000" is not present?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using direct html form tag. It was strangely not working before so I posted the question however it seems that I did something wrong. I should have tested better before posting this question and waiting for an hour.